# Java Thread Management

Tags: java, multithreading, processor

I have been looking for an architecture where my processor contains a set number of threads, say 10 or 20, and each thread has its own processing queue. The processor will select a thread on the basis of availability. 
How can I implement such a model, any idea?

Comment: Are you sure you're not reinventing the wheel? This sounds like Thread pools: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Comment: I think [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) can help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

look up `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)`. For each of the threads, you can also set a priority value.

Comment: yes i could reach my requirement. but can i have my own java  implementation of executor ?

Comment: Did you want a ready-made system or did you want to implement a scheduler yourself?

Comment: I am looking for my own implementation of scheduler. any help?

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood your question. Try a book on operating systems- wikipedia is a good place to start your research. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)#Scheduling_disciplines